# Find the second highest Score in a cricket match

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

In a cricket match, the runs made by players of both teams are stored in two arrays. The sizes of the array can be variable based on the wickets being taken by the other team. Find the second highest score after the entire match.

Example Input: arr1 = {25, 45, 43, 67, 82};

arr2 = {30, 18, 10, 90, 85};

Output: 85

My Approach: Sort both the arrays and then take two variables max and second_Max and based on conditioning find the second highest score. But, I am not able to get efficient solution.

Please help me in solving this array based problem. And if you could consider all the corner cases.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Convert and join both arrays into java.util.List, sort it using Collections.sort (descending) and pick the 2nd element.

Comment: ...or do it in O(N) ;) https://jdoodle.com/ia/zdo

Comment: only "corner case" I see: multiple players have max score. with the above solution the output would be (equal to) max score.

Comment: ..and "absolute corner case": all players have same score/0 ...

Comment: @xerx593 Can you please tell me what does "int[]... arrs" mean. I have never used this. Does it combine both the arrays as one?

Comment: Not combine..., this method accepts (1-)N (int) arrays... It's called "varargs" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html , then just iterate over all `arrs`

Comment: More corner cases: - only 1 player;(( - invalid/negative score...;(;(